# Get posts from year from URL

Tags: php, date, parameter

I've created a page that shows content from a specific year. The year will be defined in the url. Example url: https://mpdb.space/stats/tour/?year=2019

It works perfectly when I type `year=2019` but other on other year I get a 404 page. Don't know why because the other years definitely exist. And why does it gives an error, because it's just a simple parameter in the url?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "year" is a reserved word. I've changed it to "tour" and it works perfectly.